# Encrypt file with public key using openssl EVP routines

Tags: cryptography, openssl, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to encrypt a file using public key crypto with OpenSSL. I know enough to know that for a file of any reasonable size, this can't/shouldn't be done with public key. Instead:

1) Generate random key (e.g. 256 bit)

2) Encrypt key with public key

3) Symmetric encrypt file with random key from (1) e.g AES

4) Join (2) and (3) together

5) Send (4) to wherever/whoever

This process is replicated in OpenSSL's EVP routines as "envelope encryption". I've managed to implement a decryption/encryption program using this API in C, which works fine :)

I'm wondering if you can do this process directly through OpenSSL commands rather than through the low-level API. I've tried and can generate the random key, encrypt the file etc. I then get stuck when joining the two files together - at the moment I just `cat` the two together but this doesn't seem to work. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi, I understand that this is a question of 5 years ago, but maybe someone will answer. You said that `for a file of any reasonable size, this can't/shouldn't be done with public key`. I can't understand why...Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can define your own container format, but it is probably easier to [just use CMS](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/cms.html) which handles that use case just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. user4718374 - you've nicely summarised where I've managed to get to so far, but the concatenation of key and file is where I too, got stuck. Maarten - the CMS looks interesting, do you know if that will work with the EVP_Open function for decryption at the other end?

Comment: Concatenation isn't the problem. Separating the files is.  But since your key is constant length and AES doesn't seem to change that length, you could just do `cat ekey efile` and the other side can simply get the ekey (I'm using the e prefix to denote encrypted) by extracting the first 256 bytes from the concatenated file and the rest would be the encrypted file (you could do this with dd for example).

Comment: @user4005750 I would keep myself to using CMS all the way. CMS is both available for the command line and within the API (of course, as OpenSSL is a library first and a CLI later).

Comment: @maarten-bodewes Documentation on CMS is bad, but I've got something: `openssl req -x509 -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private.pem -out public.pem -subj ‘/’ -nodes`  `openssl cms -encrypt -aes256 -binary -outform DER -in plaintext.log -out encrypted.log public.pem`  `openssl cms -decrypt -inform DER -binary -in encrypted.log -inkey private.pem -out plaintext.log`  I wanted to make sure that those commands encrypt with AES256 and then join the public-encrypted symmetric key to the output file. Also - if anyone can help with decrypting CMS using the API that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have close to zero experience with openssl, but following the manpages, I would do:

1) Generate random key (e.g. 256 bit = 32 bytes)

```
openssl rand -out key 32
```

2) Generate a pubkey privkey keypair (for testing purposes, in reality, you'd just have the pub part of someone else's keypair)

```
openssl genrsa > key.pem
```

3) Extract public part

```
openssl rsa -in key.pem  -pubout  > key.pub
```

4) Encrypt key (the random key for AES) with public key

```
openssl rsautl -in key -out ekey -pubin -inkey key.pub -encrypt -raw
```

5) Verify that ekey decrypts to key

```
  openssl rsautl -in ekey -out KEY -inkey key.pem -decrypt -raw
  cmp KEY key && echo yes
```

6) Symmetrically encrypt file with random key from (1) e.g AES

```
openssl enc  -aes-256-ecb -kfile key -in file -out efile
```

As for joining ekey with efile, I don't know what format is commonly used. You could just put those two files in an archive.

Comment: Did you verify this? It seems to me that it already fails at the first command as `openssl rand -out key 256` uses 256 for the `num` argument, while the documentation states: `num pseudo-random bytes` .

Comment: Yes, I did. All the commands work fine on my PC. Does any of it fail on yours?

Comment: No, I just took a look at the first line and saw that bytes were expected instead of bits on the command line. Note that there is a difference between "executes" and "works correctly". I think a full answer should also include a way to decrypt (I agree, my answer is very short as well, but that's because it relies on pre-existing functionality).

Comment: But it does. Step 5 illustrates how the other side would decrypt the encrypted key and it verifies that it decrypts to the correct value. Decryption for step 6 is trivial: `openssl enc -d -aes-256-ecb -kfile key -in efile` (and if you start at 6 with a dummy file such as "hello world", you can verify that this will symmetrically decrypt it correctly) .

Comment: Hmm, missed the validation, that was my mistake. All's well that ends well :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with:

`openssl cms -encrypt -in infile -out outfile -outform DER -binary cert.crt`